# Find the most recent entry for each item listed in a log file (e.g. last logged on user in login history)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with column A containing a list of computers, column B contains a user that has logged on to that computer and column C is the logon date for that user. Many computers have been logged on to by various users over the last year, so there are many records for each computer. I need to find for each computer the user who has logged on most recently and the logon date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column D, create an "IsLastUser?" column. In D2 type:

```
=IF(MAX(($A$2:$A$1000=A2)*($C$2:$C$1000))=C2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

It is an array formula, so be sure to type it using "CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER" and not just "ENTER". Now add a filter, and filter for all IsLastUser? = TRUE.

If this fails, make sure Excel recognises your date column as a valid date format. You can test this with e.g. =YEAR(C2)

Comment: Mobus, this is perfect! Thank you so much for your prompt and accurate answer!

Comment: @ScottKiddle Glad I could help. Please do check mark the solution so others may know the problem has been solved.